# how to create a free shipping coupon code in drupal commerce

Tags: rules, commerce

coupon code with free shipping ,example if coupon is applied to the order, estimated shipping rate (of $4.95) should become $0.00,i have a expedited_shipping in shipping methods with base amount of 4.95 which will be applied on order .how should i create a coupon for making the expedited shipping to amount zero.

Comment: Which commerce module are you using? have you already got a coupon type module installed? have you already got a coupon system setup, but you just want one specific one to set the shipping rate to 0? Need a bit more info

Answer (score 1):

Use [Commerce Discount](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount) and [Commerce Coupon](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_coupon).

1. Create a discount that uses the Free shipping offer.
2. Set the conditions (if any).
3. Add a coupon that links to this discount.

Now when the coupon is added to the order and the conditions (if any) are met the shipping method specified in the Free shipping offer will free.